# auto- or crosscorrelation for synchronisation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I have multiples records of  a motor sound,´I would like to synchronize them first and than  calculate their sepctogram. my question is how can I use the autocorrelation or the crosscorrelation to synchronize them, I want to that to make sure  that the only " different I see " in the spectogram is related to the frequency and not to the start position of the motor or the records.

PS: I know to calculate the auto-&crosscorrelation in Matlab but I don't understand how to use them for synchronization purpose .

Answer (score 2):

Once you've calculated the cross-correlation, the location of the peak indicates the amount you need to shift one of the files to align with the other.

For example, if you have signal A and signal B, and you are using the `xcorr` function in MATLAB:

```
A = randn(1000,1);
B = circshift(A,round(randn*1000));
[val,ind]=max(abs(xcorr(A,B)));
shift = ind-length(A); % assumes A and B are same length. Otherwise use longer of the two

plot(1:length(A),A);
hold on
plot((1:length(A))+shift,B); % Two should now be aligned
```

Note that this isn't going to be perfect with noisy signals, but it should get them close if they correlate well.